# Xamarin and Visual Studio 2015 display Strange window

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with xamarin community version of "Startr". The MAIN XML does not display the application screen, but this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to buy the Business edition of Xamarin to edit .axml files. There is a 30-day trial. Starter edition won't suffice.